# Can't look around in Minecraft

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, minecraft-legacy-console

I am playing Minecraft, but the left stick no longer makes me look around. I can still sneak/crouch with the left stick though. It has been happening ever since I tried to download a map.

I have tried restarting the game as well as the console, I have ejected the disk, played a new game, and came back on.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Is your controller broken?

Comment: What kind of Xbox do you have? 360, One, etc?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ They have an [tag:xbox-360].

Answer (score 2):

That should be your sensitivity for the game.  Go to settings and look for the 'reset to default'  buton. Click it.  That should make you be able to look around again, it fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Pause the game and go to options then setting , and then on the bottom press a on reset defaults.